# RDLC Subreport footer not showing on the main report

Tags: vb.net, reporting, rdlc

Is there a way we can display the subreport footer on the main report and how?

My reports contains different footer for every page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

page headers and page foots from a subreport will not show.
you need to put footer info on the main report inside the list right under the subreport object.